# Filter many-to-many object with specific value

Tags: django, django-views, django-filter

I have the current [filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIWMa.png)

this filter works, but I also want to filter the objects inside my quotation if the user matches.

If I have 2 itens, one is from the user 1 and the other from user 2, when I filter the quotation using user 1, I also want to see only the item that has the specified user.

Thus, [instead of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTWkz.png)

[I want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nOKZ.png)

Comment: Please could you post code in your question rather than as linked images? It makes it much easier to review your issue and provide help

Comment: Not qualified to do so yet, unfortunately it needs to be linked images. Sorry.

The filter is: queryset = "queryset.filter(itens__userId=user, itens__approve=3).distinct()"

As a result I get the quotation and all itens. But I also want to know if there is a way to filter the itens per user on the same filter page

Comment: Looks like it filters the user already as you have `items__usedId=user`, are you definitely returning the correct queryset?